# Accessing form variables in a dynamic dijit.dialog (content of which is from href)

Tags: zend-framework, dynamic, dojo, zend-form

I have the following code to create a dijit.diagram which loads a form from an external link:

```
function openDialog(userID)
{ 
    composeDialog = new dijit.Dialog({
        id: 'composeDialog',
        title: 'Compose a Message', 
        style: 'width: 400px',
        href: 'myform.php?userID='+userID
    });
    composeDialog.show();
}
```

Now inside my href I have a form that asks the user for several pieces of information, but I am unable to access any of the values. Also if the form is actually submitted, then the user is re-directed to the proper page but none of the variables are passed along. When I try to access my form with `dijit.byId('myform')` all I get is a null object. Does anybody have any idea?

Thank you very much!

Comment: When you say the "user is re-directed to the proper page," is the dialog's form sending a `POST` request to the server and the server sending back proper page as its response?

Comment: Yeah the POST request was sent but without any of the variables. I actually ended up reworking that part of the program to not use an external page as the content source for the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is not executed in `dijit.Dialog`. Use `dojox.widget.DialogSimple` instead. See this [reference](http://dojo.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/widget/DialogSimple.html#dojox-widget-dialogsimple)

Then, pass the values of the form from the dialog to the page using javascript.